# Command Button Page Reference Redirect Creates a URL with the Generated ID of the Element rather than the specified URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, id

I have a button that redirects to a PDF page where the same controller fills in the information for both. To accomplish this I've been using a Command Button that returns a page reference of the PDF Page.

After a Recent update to the page, both that button and another button on the page have stopped working. The update was to a completely different section and different code on the page, and should not have interfered with either button or their methods in any way.

In the case of the redirect button it now returns a URL that seems to be the pages generated ID of the HTML Element with the value of the button appended.

Visualforce:

```
<div id="buttonPanel" class="panel panel-default">
                                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <apex:commandButton style="margin-left:2px;" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" disabled="false" value="Generate Quote" action="{!gotoPage2}"/>  
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
```

Apex:

```
public PageReference gotoPage2(){
    String URL = '/apex/QuotePage';
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(URL);
    pageRef.setRedirect(false);
    return pageRef;
}
```

Starting URL:

```
https://[Instance].visual.force.com/apex/ConveniencePricing
```

Expected Redirect URL:

```
https://[Instance].visual.force.com/apex/QuotePage
```

Actual Redirect URL:

```
https://[Instance].visual.force.com/apex/ConveniencePricing?j_id0%3Aj_id30%3Aj_id237=Generate+Quote
```

Comment: Fyi you can do `pageRef = Page.QuotePage`

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for the tip! Any thoughts on why the url is not working correctly?

Comment: Why are you calling `setRedirect(false)`? I don't understand the desired behavior.

Comment: @AdrianLarson to preserve the View State data for the PDF

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong here, but I *am* sure someone on here will figure it out.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Me either, and like I said in the post this only happened after a change to an unrelated method, and some unrelated HTML code. Other buttons don't work either.

Comment: Have you got a custom sidebar component which is using JS in the background that could be causing the issue by overriding the buttons action? If a lot of your code is unmanaged in your org you could do a search in all files in dev console or similar in sublime text to look for Generate Quote to see if there is some code being accidentally picked up upon the button click.

Comment: @MichaelFleming that wasn't the case, I actually found the issue to be something I didn't even know would cause issues: two sets of <form> tags on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I've discovered is that there were two  tags on the web pag as a whole, and it caused a lot of weird issues with javascript and command buttons.

Removing one set of them fixed the issues completely.